# Raspbian gcc does not know '.intel_syntax'?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I tried to execute:

```
gcc -o main main.c squrt.S -lm -no-pie
```

This worked on a different computer, but this time it did not know a single instruction:

```
squrt.S: Assembler messages:
squrt.S:7: Error: unknown pseudo-op: `.intel_syntax'
squrt.S:12: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `#'
squrt.S:17: Error: bad instruction `movq rax,xmm0#Bits from xmm0 to rax'
squrt.S:18: Error: bad instruction `shl rax,1'
squrt.S:19: Error: bad instruction `shr rax,53#Exponent of the argument'
squrt.S:20: Error: ARM register expected -- `cmp rax,2047#checks if x is real'
squrt.S:21: Error: bad instruction `je end'
squrt.S:22: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rcx,1#sgn(x)'
squrt.S:23: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,0'
squrt.S:24: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm1,rax'
squrt.S:25: Error: bad instruction `comisd xmm0,xmm1#vergleicht die double xmm0,xmm1 und setzt das Statusregister entsprechend'
squrt.S:26: Error: bad instruction `jae notNegative#Sprung wenn double x in xmm0>=0.0'
squrt.S:27: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rcx,-1#x<0,deswegen sgn(x)=-1'
squrt.S:28: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm1,rcx'
squrt.S:29: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm0,xmm1'
squrt.S:31: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm2,[power]'
squrt.S:32: Error: bad instruction `comisd xmm0,xmm2'
squrt.S:33: Error: bad instruction `jbe nichtriesig'
squrt.S:34: Error: bad instruction `call ln#|x|>2^28'
squrt.S:35: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm1,[ln2]'
squrt.S:36: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm0,xmm1'
squrt.S:37: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm1,rcx'
squrt.S:38: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm0,xmm1'
squrt.S:39: Error: bad instruction `ret #arsinh(x):=sgn(x)(ln(x)+ln(2))'
squrt.S:41: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm1,xmm0'
squrt.S:42: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm0,xmm0'
squrt.S:43: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,1'
squrt.S:44: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm2,rax'
squrt.S:45: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm0,xmm2'
squrt.S:46: Error: bad instruction `call .Lsqrt'
squrt.S:47: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm0,xmm1'
squrt.S:48: Error: bad instruction `call ln'
squrt.S:49: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm1,rcx'
squrt.S:50: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm0,xmm1'
squrt.S:52: Error: bad instruction `ret'
squrt.S:65: Error: bad instruction `movq rdx,xmm0'
squrt.S:66: Error: bad instruction `shr rdx,52#Mantisse wegschieben'
squrt.S:68: Error: ARM register expected -- `sub rdx,1022#e+1'
squrt.S:70: Error: bad instruction `movq rax,xmm0'
squrt.S:71: Error: bad instruction `shl rax,12#setze Vorzeichen'
squrt.S:72: Error: bad instruction `shr rax,12#und Exponenten auf 0'
squrt.S:73: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rdi,1022'
squrt.S:74: Error: bad instruction `shl rdi,52#verschiebe(-1+1023)in die oberen 12 bit von rdi(oder genauer gesagt 11 Bit,das 12. wird nicht verändert)'
squrt.S:75: Error: ARM register expected -- `add rax,rdi#neuer Exponent mit alter Mantisse m durch Addition'
squrt.S:76: Error: bad instruction `movq xmm0,rax#enthält m*0,5'
squrt.S:77: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,1'
squrt.S:78: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm3,rax#xmm3=1'
squrt.S:79: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm4,xmm3'
squrt.S:80: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm4,xmm3#2'
squrt.S:81: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm1,xmm3#1=2k+1,da k am Anfang 0 ist'
squrt.S:82: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm5,xmm0#x'
squrt.S:83: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm6,xmm0#x'
squrt.S:84: Error: bad instruction `subsd xmm5,xmm3#x-1'
squrt.S:85: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm6,xmm3#x+1'
squrt.S:86: Error: bad instruction `divsd xmm5,xmm6#((x-1)/(x+1))^(2k+1),wobei k noch 0'
squrt.S:87: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm7,xmm5'
squrt.S:88: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm7,xmm7#(x-1)/(x+1)^2'
squrt.S:89: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,0'
squrt.S:90: Error: bad instruction `movq xmm0,rax#0'
squrt.S:91: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rsi,5'
squrt.S:93: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm2,xmm4#2'
squrt.S:94: Error: bad instruction `divsd xmm2,xmm1#2/(2k+1)'
squrt.S:95: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm2,xmm5#2/(2k+1))*(((x-1)/(x+1))^(2k+1))'
squrt.S:96: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm0,xmm2'
squrt.S:97: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm1,xmm4'
squrt.S:98: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm5,xmm7'
squrt.S:99: Error: bad instruction `dec rsi'
squrt.S:100: Error: bad instruction `jg lnLoop'
squrt.S:102: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm1,[ln2]'
squrt.S:103: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm2,rdx'
squrt.S:104: Error: bad instruction `mulsd xmm1,xmm2'
squrt.S:105: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm0,xmm1#(ln(x)+(exponent+1)*ln(2))'
squrt.S:106: Error: bad instruction `ret'
squrt.S:109: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm13,xmm0'
squrt.S:110: Error: bad instruction `movq rax,xmm0'
squrt.S:111: Error: bad instruction `shl rax,1'
squrt.S:112: Error: bad instruction `shr rax,53'
squrt.S:113: Error: ARM register expected -- `sub rax,1023'
squrt.S:114: Error: ARM register expected -- `add rax,1'
squrt.S:115: Error: bad instruction `sar rax,1'
squrt.S:116: Error: ARM register expected -- `add rax,1023'
squrt.S:117: Error: bad instruction `shl rax,52'
squrt.S:118: Error: bad instruction `movq xmm0,rax'
squrt.S:119: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm15,xmm0'
squrt.S:120: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm0,xmm13'
squrt.S:122: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,2'
squrt.S:123: Error: bad instruction `cvtsi2sd xmm14,rax#2'
squrt.S:124: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov rax,8#Anzahl Wiederholungen-1'
squrt.S:126: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm13,xmm0'
squrt.S:127: Error: bad instruction `divsd xmm13,xmm15'
squrt.S:128: Error: bad instruction `addsd xmm13,xmm15'
squrt.S:129: Error: bad instruction `divsd xmm13,xmm14'
squrt.S:130: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm15,xmm13'
squrt.S:131: Error: bad instruction `dec rax'
squrt.S:132: Error: bad instruction `jle sqrtEnd'
squrt.S:133: Error: bad instruction `jmp sqrtLoop'
squrt.S:135: Error: bad instruction `movsd xmm0,xmm13'
squrt.S:136: Error: bad instruction `ret'
make: *** [Makefile:2: main] Fehler 1
```

Is there some package I have to install?

Comment: What CPU do you have in your pi?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The OP never stated that they were using a Raspberry Pi to run Raspbian. https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/

Comment: @Aron Sorry. Lett me re-phrase: What CPU do you have in your device?

Answer (score 15):

The "assembly" language is architecture-dependent, since its very point is to directly write CPU instructions, and each CPU type has different ones. Your entire program is written in amd64 / Intel x86_64 assembly code, but Raspbian doesn't run on those – it runs on ARM devices, and so the standard `gcc` that comes it also expects ARM assembly.

(Take a look at `lscpu` and `gcc -dumpmachine` to find out what CPU type you have.)

If you want the program to run on ARM CPUs, you have to rewrite all of it. There's (probably) no gcc package that can compile x86 assembly to run on ARM, though there *might* be translators to help you with rewriting.

If you want the program to run on amd64/x86_64 CPUs, but only compile it on Raspbian, you have to install a cross-compiler. (It might be in gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu + binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu.)

Comment: And this is why people write in C, which (very roughly) started as architecture-independent assembly.

Comment: Not strictly true. There is an official flavour of Raspbian which will compile and run that code with zero modification. https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/